# Quantity button is not increasing or decreasing items in "for" loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, increment, decrement

I am trying to increase/decrease the quantity of an item by the input I get from HTML Page. When I try to click on inc/dec button it just increments/decrements my first element within the `for` loop. For example:
If I have a 1st item input as 1 ... now I try to increment the second item through inc button, it changes the 1st item input from 1-->2 making 1st item quantity as 2 and my second items remains unchanged as 1.. same continues if I click on 3rd or 4th item

Here's part of a code from my `html` page

```
{% for item in order.get_cart_items %}
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row" class="border-0">
                    <div class="p-2">
                      <img src="{{item.product.product_img.url}}" alt="" width="70" class="img-fluid rounded shadow-sm">
                      <div class="ml-3 d-inline-block align-middle">
                        <h5 class="mb-0"> <a href="#" class="text-dark d-inline-block align-middle">{{ item.product.name }}</a></h5><span class="text-muted font-weight-normal font-italic d-block">Category: {{ item.product.product_type }}</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </th>
                  <td class="border-0 align-middle"><strong>Rs.{{ item.product.price}}</strong></td>
                  <td class="border-0 align-middle"><strong><form>
                    <div class="value-button" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue()" value="Decrease Value">-</div>
                    <input type="number" id="number" value="1" />
                    <div class="value-button" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue()" value="Increase Value">+</div>
                  </form></strong></td>
                  <td class="border-0 align-middle"><a href="{% url 'delete-item' item.id %}" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>               
                </tr>
{% endfor %}
.
.
.
<script>
                  function increaseValue() {
                  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
                  value = isNaN(value) ? 1 : value;
                  value++;
                  document.getElementById('number').value = value;
                }

                function decreaseValue() {
                  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
                  value = isNaN(value) ? 1 : value;
                  value < 2 ? value = 2 : '';
                  value--;
                  document.getElementById('number').value = value;
                }
</script>
```

Comment: You have this within a foreach loop: `<input type="number" id="number" value="1" />`. And then your function is modifying `document.getElementById('number').value`. You can't use the same id on multiple elements, because JavaScript doesn't know which id you mean to modify.

Comment: So what should I do now?? Any ideas..?? Can I refer the elements by class name...??

Comment: Sure, as long as you understand and agree to that (that id's must be unique), I'll whip up a quick answer...

Comment: Can do the same thing by getElementsByClassName('Number')...I believe class name can be unique

Comment: Hi, Sanjay: I posted an answer.  I don't really know what language you're using there server-side, so, I made some guesses in the syntax.  I think you'll get the id I'm going for, though.

Comment: Hey, Sanjay: Let me know if that helped!  Please mark the answer correct, if it is, so it can help others with this issue know what the solution was.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, the id's of your elements need to be unique.  Especially so when doing `getElementById()` calls in JavaScript.

You need to change both your server-side `foreach` loop and your client-side `increaseValue()`/`decreaseValue()` functions.

You need to change them in this way: Assign a unique id in your foreach loop, pass the id as an argument to the `increaseValue()`/`decreaseValue()` functions, and then update those functions to use the argument passed.  Notice, below, we need an index, which I call `{i}`, which is used to make your `id` unique.  This needs to be incremented in each iteration of the `foreach` loop.

So, in your foreach, (special thanks for the code improvement updates to @Sanjay)...

```
{% for item in order.get_cart_items %}
    ...
        <div class="value-button" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue({forloop.counter})" value="Decrease Value">-</div>
        <input type="number" id="{forloop.counter}" value="1" />
        <div class="value-button" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue({forloop.counter})" value="Increase Value">+</div>
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

The rendered HTML should look like: `<input ... id="number1" ... />`, `<input ... id="number2" ... />`, `<input ... id="number3" ... />`, etc..  Notice, the id properties are unique.

And then, in both your increase/decrease functions, adjust them as follows to accept an argument for `id`, and then to use that `id`...

```
function increaseValue(id) {
      var value = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value, 10);
      value = isNaN(value) ? 1 : value;
      value++;
      document.getElementById(id).value = value;
}
```

Make this change for *both* of your functions.  The changes are basically the same for both, so, I'm only listing one.

Now your JavaScript will work on the particular `id` given to it.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the logic man. I tried the same logic in Django Template. But it doesn't work as expected. I made the following changes `onclick="increaseValue(number{{forloop.counter}})" ` in `div` tag and `id="number{{forloop.counter}}"` in `input` tag. Inspecting element it shows this way `onclick="decreaseValue(number1)"` `id="number1"`.....`onclick="decreaseValue(number2)"` `id="number2"`...``onclick="decreaseValue(number3)"` `id="number3"``...the `id` value is taken correctly but the script is not working.

Comment: This works---> `onclick="increaseValue({{forloop.counter}})"` and `id="number{{forloop.counter}}"` it just passes the loop count value to id arguement

Comment: Excellent!  `forloop.counter` is just what I was looking for!  Perfect, this looks great.  I updated the code up above with your code suggestions, and also added credit to you, @Sanjay, for the code improvements.  Let me know if this answer is ready for takeoff! =)

Comment: just make this change `number{{forloop.counter}}` --> `{{forloop.counter}}`. Works only in **django template**

Comment: @Sanjay : Done!  Looks like I forgot to properly define the number input id, but, yeap, good now, thanks!